# Combining 2 audio files is Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avaudiofile

I am trying to combine 2 audio files.

The main problem is that audio files are lossless **.flac** files.

I tried creating `AVMutableComposition`, then creating 2 `AVURLAsset` for each audio and use `AVAssetExportSession` to combine the audio files and it works, but the main problem in this case is that `AVAssetExportSession` doesn't support exporting to **.flac** and supports **.m4a** which is lossy compression and not suitable in my case.

Can anyone suggest how to get **.flac** audio files ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and if someone is wondering, here is the solution:

Instead of `AVAssetExportSession`, I used `AVAudioEngine`, but for that to work you will have to connect at least 1 `AVAudioPlayerNode` to it.
Then create 2 `AVAudioFile` from the audio files that want to combine and schedule them to play on connected `AVAudioPlayerNode` one after another. After that `AVAudioPCMBuffer` is needed to render frames manually in a `while` loop and store it on disk on some sort of a container (I used **.mov** temporary file for this).
After everything is done you can just rename the file to a correct **.flac** file and it will work.